# Speeding up Bloomberg session start

Tags: bloomberg

I am using the following VBA code to begin a Bloomberg session:

```
  Set Sess = New Session

    Dim Opt As SessionOptions
    Set Opt = Sess.CreateSessionOptions

    Opt.ServerHost = "127.0.0.1"
    Opt.ServerPort = 8194

    Sess.SetSessionOptions Opt

    Sess.Start
```

It works but takes 15-20 seconds.  I can live with that if I must, but it seems odd because there was no such delay using their old Bloomberg Data control.  Is there a way to speed things up, say, by connecting to an existing Bloomberg process, or some other option I don't know about?

Comment: That sounds like a lot of time - I have never seen it take more than a few (3-5) seconds. You also have the option to start it asynchronously so you can do something useful while waiting...

Answer (score 0):

It can take a while to start the first session after logging into the Terminal, but should be quicker for subsequent sessions. If you want to avoid a long start in your application you can run Excel and use the API for any retrieval of data. For example, type this formula in a cell in Excel: `"=BDP("IBM US Equity","PX_LAST")` and then run your application.